# Axiom of Regularity and Self-Containment

Tags: foundations

I understand that the axiom of
Regularity excludes $A=\{A\}$ but what about $A=\{A, \emptyset \}$?

Comment: It excludes $A=\{\emptyset, \{A\}\}$ or $A=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset, A\}\}\}\}$, or anything like that where $A$ is a member of some element of (an element of an element of...) $A.$

Answer (score 5):

By pairing+comprehension there exists a set $B=\{A,A\}=\{A\}$ and then $B\cap A=\{A\}\cap\{A, \emptyset\}=\{A\}\ne\emptyset$, and since $A$ is the only member of $B$, $B$ violates the axiom of regularity.

Answer (score 1):

If $A = \{A,\emptyset\}$ then $A \in A$ which is impossible with Regularity.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted… it’s not wrong.